# Pandas: get the unique value with the biggest index

Tags: pandas

I have a df like this

```
    Name    Data   
0   Mike    123    
1   Mike    456    
2   Mike    789    
3   Fred    345
4   Fred    123
5   Ted     333
```

I need to get unique `Name` with the max index value

output:

```
    Name    Data   
0   Mike    789    
1   Fred    123
2   Ted     333
```

Comment: From the duplicate `df.groupby('Name').tail(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Step 1st:*** Import `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd
```

***Step 2nd:*** Copy OP's df values.

***Step 3rd:*** Now run following command to create data frame from OP's samples.

```
df=pd.read_clipboard()
```

***Step 4th:*** Run following code to remove duplicates and keep last value of Name column.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='Name',keep='last')
```

Output will be as follows.

```
   Name   Data
2   Mike   789 
4   Fred   123 
5   Ted    333
```

Comment: wow. Amazingly simple. Thanks. This answer is so much better than the groupby solutions. So easy to understand and readable. ... Also.. +1 for the `read_clipboard()`... didn't know you could do that... that's also amazing!